# Beginner problems with exercise

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I have a problem with this exercise:

```py
# Loop through the letters of the variable 'summer_word' from above
# Concatenate the consonants from 'summer_word' and answer with the new word.

summer_word = "music"
```

Tip: Create a string that contains consonants and check if each letter is in it.

I now how to loop through the letters in the word, but i can't figure out how to take out the consonants.

Comment: You may want to look into 'regular expression' or 'regex' in short.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code, might help your case:

```
summer_word = "music"
consonants = "b, c, d, f, g, j, k, l, m, n, p, q, s, t, v, x, z , h, r, w, y"
new_word = " "

for letter in summer_word:
   if letter in consonants:
        new_word += letter
print(new_word)
```

Comment: giving the solution away won't make a beginner learn any faster

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down. You should:

- hardcode all the consonants into a single string e.g.

```py
consonants = 'qwrt...'
```

- loop over the characters of the string stored in the `summer_word` variable
- check if the character at hand is included in the `consonants` string

```py
for letter in summer_word:
    # do stuff...
```

- if the letter is in the consonants string, store it into a new string

```py
if letter in consonants:
    # ...
```

this should be more than enough to get you started :) happy learning